# HTMLpurifier how to that instead of deleting any tags (e.g. script) it handles them with the htmlspecialchars function?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

HTMLpurifier how to that instead of deleting any tags (e.g. script) it handles them with the htmlspecialchars function? I want that instead of removing the tag, he made him incompetent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting [`Core.EscapeInvalidTags`](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.EscapeInvalidTags) should be what you're looking for.